# I Want to make menu with Toggle menu in AMP

Tags: amp-html

I Want to make  menu with Toggle menu in AMP using style without java script or jquery, I follow this solution which in this link http://www.da-agency.de/accelerated-mobile-pages-build-mobile-navigation-amp-html/ but the menu just opened when hover,I want the menu Open when click on toggle button.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for hamburger menu then amphtml community has launched a sidebar component you can find the demo at https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-sidebar/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try into a mobile browser or with the Chrome inspector using the "toggle device mode" to test the page as in a mobile device ?
I just did and the menu opens on tap/click, not on hover

but after a few tests I suggest you put your menu into a lightbox, otherwise you won't be able to close the menu with only CSS as in the example you use.

check this out https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-lightbox/

all amp extensions are listed here :

- https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/README.md

and you ll find a full list of examples in the projects github